# how to match with grep and output in the same line?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

I have a file consisting of md5 hashes and mail addresses. I can match the patterns separately but I need to know how to display them on the same line.

sample file.txt

> '123123123'|'blahblah'|'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'|'test@test.com'
> '123423124'|'blahblahblahblah'|'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'|'another@test.com'

i need an output like this one:

> test@test.com::202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
> another@test.com::202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
> ...

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `sed` or better here with `awk`?

Comment: grep -o "[0-9a-f]\{32\}" file.txt  // to match de md5 hash\
grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" file.txt //match email\

i intent to do a grep with double pattern but it didn't work cuz one of the grep use -E and the other not

Comment: what are you trying to match? If you're just trying to extract columns 4 and 3, `awk -F "/^'|'[|]'|'$" '{print $4"::"$3}'`

Comment: @jhnc ohh, thank you! this solve my problem.